# how to use django-ratelimit for graphene resolve

Tags: django, graphene-python

We cannot use `django-ratelimit` directly for graphql resolve method.
Because the default decorator is get request from the first argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a [simple decorator](https://o3o3o.me/2019/07/13/django-ratelimit-for-graphql/), which can support key like `gql:xxxx` with `django-ratelimit`, here is demo:

```
class TestMutaion(graphene.Mutation):
  class Arguments:
    phone = graphene.String(required=True)

  ok = graphene.Boolean()

  @ratelimit(key="gql:phone", rate="5/m", block=True) # here key: 'gql:phone'
  def mutate(self, info, phone):
    request = info.context
    # Do sth
    return TestMutaion(ok=True)
```

Comment: I have added the snippet into the simple pkg:  https://pypi.org/project/django-graphql-ratelimit/